# Does each QT widget have a 'show' signal?

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to do some action when a dialog shows when it opens or when it maximizes from a minimal status or it moves from out of a screen.

Does QT have such a signal?
I am also not sure where to find if QT has a list of signals defined.

Comment: I don't think so, but you can reimplement QWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *) to emit your own signal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does each QT widget have a 'show' signal?

If you look at Qt source code then you will find QWidget::show to be a slot:

```
public Q_SLOTS:
    // Widget management functions

    virtual void setVisible(bool visible);
    void setHidden(bool hidden);
    void show();
```

The slot is mainly for us, programmers to make us able to connect with signals for specific purposes like clicking the button we created does something to certain widget. As for Windows or Mac OS, we have the app serving all the events coming from the system via event loop. And QWidget reacts on all the 'signals' in the form of system events coming and yes, may, execute `show()` or `showMaximized()` or `showMinimized` slots then.

But I can assume you want to overload

```
virtual void showEvent(QShowEvent *);
virtual void hideEvent(QHideEvent *);
```

Like:

```
void MyWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *e)
{
    if (isMaximized())
    {
         if (e->spontaneous())
         {
             // the author would like to know
             // if the event is issued by the system
         }
         ; // the action for maximized
    }
    else
    {
         ; // the action for normal show
    }
}

void MyWidget::hideEvent(QHideEvent *)
{
    if (isMinimized())
    {
         ; // the action for minimized
    }
    else
    {
         ; // the action for hide
    }
}
```

For recognizing cases when the system operates the widget we can use [QEvent::spontaneous()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#spontaneous).

Please also refer to show and hide event doc pages:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshowevent-members.html
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhideevent.html

Comment: This seems what I need to do. I am new to QT. Does it mean we need to override the show method? It is defined under public Q_SLOTS. Is it virtual?

Comment: You only overload the event handler and do whatever you want there.

Comment: I found showEvent is called when a widget is shown in the first time or maximized; but isMaximized() does not return true for some reason. showEvent is not called when minimized, I think I may want to use hideEvent at the case.

Comment: Yes, the event handler is happening for both programmatic and system issued events. And hideEvent helps as well. Please see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#spontaneous

Comment: "Due to limitations on some window systems, this does not always report the expected results (e.g., if the user on X11 maximizes the window via the window manager, Qt has no way of distinguishing this from any other resize). This is expected to improve as window manager protocols evolve." This is what QT doc says about the isMaximized method, if so, we cannot really know if it is maximized or not...?

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't write for X11 but I would try to check the dimensions of widget rectangle against     QRect desktopRect = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry(this);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102415/discussion-between-joe-c-and-alexandervx).

Comment: Sorry. I think I understood what happens now. What I did is not maximize, I made the dialog minimized into tool bars, and then clicked it to resume it. This is not called 'Maximized'. What I wanted is that I only want to apply my action when the dialog is shown the first time, and do nothing if it is minimzed, resumed, or moved. If so, I guess I just need to override show? or Is there a way, in showEvent, to know whether this is the first time a widget is shown?